# Only display 'Edit' link on certain rows on apex report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following report structure which shows sales targets and sales for products throughout the year.
Each product will have two rows: a row showing sales and a row showing sales_target. Currently my report has an edit link next to every line on the report. Is there a way to remove the edit link from the sales_target rows?

```
select 'red ball'"Product",'sales'"type",'1'"jan",'11'"feb",'31'"mar",'41'"apr",'61'"may",'15'"jun",'15'"jul",'1'"aug",'1'"sep",'21'"oct",'14'"nov",'61'"dec",'Edit' "Edit record" from dual
```

I thought i code write somewhere a condition on the column to only show the 'edit' link on the row if the sales type is sales and not sales_target?

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usally i use something like this:

1. In "Edit Column" -> "Column Link" -> "Link Attributes" add the folowing string:

   ```
   class="#TYPE#"
   ```
2. Add this css style to your page:

   ```
   .sales_target { display: none; }
   ```

Your link will look like:

```
<a href="#" class="sales_target">sales_target_edit</a>
 or
<a href="#" class="sales">sales_edit</a>
```

All links with class="sales_target" will hide.

Comment: Good idea. I usually am a bit too trigger-happy on using jquery for these things. CSS is a good option!

Comment: @Blob You can add CSS on the page itself by editing the page. If you are on apex 4.2 then you will have an "Inline CSS" textarea, where you can simply copy and paste the above css rule. If not on 4.2, then you will have to add the css in style tags in the header section of the page through `<style type="text/css">...</style>`

Comment: I think that using dynamic action is not good idea. Iterating over all rows and removing edit link after each report refresh... Hmmm... I think it is very bad. And what will be if you rename your report column name TYPE? What will be if report temlate changes? What will be if you change theme of application? What if you add another link column? Are you sure that this code will work anywhere and you will not remove any other links?

Comment: The most correct will be to divide data and metadata. In sql-source of report add flag, that will indicate: show edit link or not. Because, today it will be one condition, another day it will be another. And if condition changes, you must change only this flag condition, without changing you UI.

Comment: I agree though. The javascript is more prone to not working after some such change, while the css will. Not only that, it requires more knowledge of the generated html (or template) and you have to understand selectors a lot better. Ideally, @Blob tries to implement this. I'd say that it is pretty trivial, and less complex than seen in the comments on my answer above (which immediately proved that a structure change can instantly break things actually). But okay, not all apex apps are big and have 50+ users, and using CSS or JS is a rather trivial choice as long as either is used correct.

Comment: Even though i have got your method working and looks great, I shall try the method @NoGotnu has provided as above comments have worried me. This method will also fail though if i change the name of the column, so isnt this a '6 and two 3's' situation? Plus what happens if i add another category, in the JS i switch it from == to !=, however how would you use the CSS method for 'PRIOR SALES' lets say for last year?

Comment: Look at my comment above. I think you must add new column, named for example edit_flag, and set this flag with sql-condition in your sql-source of report. It will be the most right way. Because flag is a metadata, that affects UI, not data. And when you add another category, or change condition, you will not have change your UI, you will have change only condition in the sql. (sorry for my english).

Comment: `select
  column1,
  column2,
  type,
  case when type in ('some_type', 'some_type2', 'some_type3') then 'Y' else 'N' end show_flag
 from tab1 t`

Answer (score 1):

Setting the condition on a column will cause the column to be either displayed or not for the whole column, not for a specific row.

One possible solution might be to remove the extra column link through javascript.
Run this code in a dynamic action, after refresh of the report. Execute javascript, execute on page load checked. I gave my report region a static id, which is "rStatic" in the code.

```
$("#report_rStatic .report-standard td[headers='TYPE']").each(function(){
  if($(this).text()=='SALES'){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td[headers='EDIT_RECORD'] a").remove();
  };
});
```

This will loop over all cells in the `TYPE` column, and when the type is `SALES` it will remove the anchor tag in the `EDIT_RECORD` column.

Comment: Stuggling with this one Tom, ive done as instructed but doesnt seem to be working. I even put an alert in the dynamic action to test it was firing when the report was refreshed (and it popped up). Is it maybe because i have the report in another region maybe? or maybe because i have a dynamic action that generates the report based on changes of two text field? I did add the javascript to that dynamic action after the refresh but still no joy. Do i need to install any libraries?

Comment: It could be the jQuery selector really. What name did you use for the static for the report region? I notice now that I may not have spelled this out enough, but when you use `rStatic` as static id, the selector still has to be `report_rStatic`, to narrow the search. There is also the `.report-standard` which I use to select only the table with the report in it, but ultimately this can depend on the report template (or theme, by extension). You might try it without `.report-standard` in there. If you really are stuck, make a small example on apex.oracle.com and I can take a look there for you.

Comment: i just used your name for now, i called the report rStatic. Would it matter that its an interactive report? I give it another go and if not ill do as requested. Thank you

Comment: If it's an IR then certainly drop the `.report-standard`

Comment: Ive created the functionality of my page online. The text fields filter the report but havent done that functionality, just trying to get the edit button display working at the moment for sales rows. You can see it at http://apex.oracle.com and login as s: apps2, u: user, p: DynamicAction2

Comment: @Blob I made some adjustments. My original answer aimed at a classic report, not an interactive one. The markup is very different between these, and thus selectors are too. It's also not really necessary to set a static id, since we use dynamic action and a defined triggering element. In the case of a region, the region is this triggering element, and can be used easily in the javascript context. Also, the test for a header has to use uppercase, since the header is. Check the DA, but it now has this: `$("td[headers='TYPE']", this.triggeringElement)`