# Making a row read only in a tabular form

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a tabular form which users will update on a yearly basis for their targets. Each product will have three rows: a row showing sales (last year), a row showing sales_target (sales man will enter) and a manager figure (what the manager expects the sales man should sell). The user should only be able to view sales from last year and the managers figure, and be able to enter into sales_targets. I know how to make columns readable but stuck on how to make a row readable if its not manager figure and sales.

There was some javascript that i could maybe use from another post however that is for a column rather than a row, could something similiar maybe used? [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056575/only-display-edit-link-on-certain-rows-on-apex-report)

I have made a demo here:

Link:[apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com)
workspace: apps2
user: user
password: DynamicAction2
application name: Application 71656 Read only Rows for Tabular Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, something similar can be used (execute this on page load):

```
$('#TAB_REP').find('td[headers="TYPE"]:contains(manager figure)').siblings('td').children('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

where TAB_REP is static ID of your report.

I have try to use more simple way - by defining attribute of the column, but in tabular report, apex dosn't replace #COLUMN# strings. Hope this is not a bug.

P.S. I've changed your demo.

Comment: Could this be used for tha sales_target row as well as the manager figure row?

Comment: Yes. jQuery selector will be: `$('#TAB_REP').find('td[headers="TYPE"]').filter(':contains(manager figure), :contains(sales_target)').siblings('td').children('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: Use this method with care. Be aware that disabled items DO NOT POST to the server! Submitting a tabular form where items have been set to disabled will inevitably lead to errors on submit since checksums will fail. There is also the issue that you only cover INPUT items here, and not select lists, nor LOV items or datepickers. For those last 2 setting disabled will only disable the input item but not the associated icons.

Comment: @Tom Darn it..the data is not to be edited, but worried about the leading to errors bit. What approach would you take, maybe use a condition or dynamic action?

Comment: @Blob You could use the `readonly` property instead of the `disabled`  one. However, this only works on input fields, and not on select lists. Plus setting input fields which are part of a datepicker or lov will not remove the associated widget or icons. That doesn't have to be an issue though if these are not the types of fields you want to have changed.

Comment: @Tom But at least i know of 2 ways now which is all good. The rows that are disabled will never require modification by any user. Now I'm just fighting on with putting the above in a dynamic action since the user selects from a drop down menu which refreshes the form, this means i cant use the above on the page and instead must be inside the dynamic action.

Comment: @blob As long as you don't mean 'disabled' items in a 'disabled' row as being 'disabled' with the property 'disabled'. In a wizard generated tabular form you will have checksums for each row, and since disabling an item prevents it from being substituted to session state (the f-arrays) this will cause the check on checksums to fail. In a manual tabular form you won't have this, but still your session-state arrays will be incorrectly filled as suddenly you won't have as many rows as there should: especially a pitfall in comparison code server-side!

Comment: @Tom Ive used read only instead which works the same, prevents them from editing the information. The above works on the intial page load but ive moved it into a dynamic action since it was enabling them to edit the rows if they changed the customer in the select list. Its like the jquery isnt firing in the dynamic action. Is this a new stack overflow question?

Comment: @Blob set the da to fire after refresh of the report, and check fire on page load on the true action