# Making a Row Read Only in a tabular form based on table value

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a tabular form which is updated throughout the year and i wanted to prevent users from editing certain rows. Currently the 'row type' is hard coded however I want the application admin to control which 'row types' are readable / write at certain times. [My answered question, click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188966/making-a-row-read-only-in-a-tabular-form)

Currently a dynamic action is fired which prevents the rows that contain the type 'manager figure' and 'sales_target' being edited.

I have created a table with the three row types against each customer. Each status is set by a number: 0 to 3 (These i will decode into something meaningful for users).

- 0 - Row with that row type is read only.
- 1 - Users can enter into the row with that row type.
- 2 - row is read only with that row type.
- 3 - row is complete and set to read only.

I have created a new form (new tab) for the admin user to maintain each status.

Currently for Customer 'Big Toy Store' rows should be set as follows:

- Manager Figure row should be read only (since set to 2)
- Sales should be readable (since set to 0)
- Sales target should be writable (since set to 1)

Please can i be pointed in the right direction, ive looked into jquery but struggling to work out how to pass the output of an sql query to it, so it can be used to determine which rows should be read only.

Link:[apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com)
workspace: apps2
user: developer.user
password: DynamicAction
application name: Application 71656 Read only Rows for Tabular Form

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a tabular form is a good format to work out this idea. As you can see, you require quite a bit of javascript to produce the results you want. Not only that, but this is all client side too, and thus there are some security risks to take into account. After all, I could just run some Firebug and disable or revert all things you did, and even change the numbers. Especially with sales figures, which is something you most definitely do want altered by everybody and is also the nature of your question, security is important.
There are more elegant ways here for you to control this, and not in the least to reduce the amount of highly customized javascript code. For example, you could do away with the tabular form, and instead implement a modal popup from an interactive report. Since the modal popup would be an iframe and thus a different page, you can create a form page. On a form page you have  a lot more control over what happens to certain elements. You can specify conditions, read-only conditions, or use authorization schemes. All things you can not evidently use in a tabular form.
I'd think you'd do yourself a service by thinking this over again, and explore a different option. How much of a dealbreaker is using a tabular form actually?
You need the user. You need to know what group he belongs to, and then this has to be checked against the different statusses and rows have to be en/disabled. Do you really want this to happen on the client side?
I'm not saying it can't be done in a tabular form and javascript. It can, I'm just really doubting this is the correct approach!

Comment: Thank you for your message, do you mean the tabular that controls editable rows, or tabular form where people enter their figures? It must be a tabular form so the user can see the customers and just type in a figures where required. I did originally have them going into a form from a report and they said no. Since the post, i now use select lists to update which status has editable rows, and use an sql update to update the table, which has enabled me to remove the tabular form on admin page. Ill read up on interactive reports/model popups, bit worried they wont like clicking.Thank you

Comment: I understand that your users might not like clicking, but from a security standpoint I don't think this kind of setup with the tabular form is a good one. When you want certain rows to not be updated by certain users, then you'd better have both client and server side validations on that. Probably ideally you'd be best off with a manual tabular form, where you can control this a great deal better. The tradeof is more code however, as you won't be able to use the builtin processes