# Oracle Apex: Add custom column into interactive report

Tags: database, oracle, report, oracle-apex

I create a page and add an **interactive report** to show data of view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT_VIEW AS
SELECT FAC_FILE.NAME as FILE_NAME, FAC_NHAN_VIEN.USERNAME as USERNAME, 
FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT.FAC_MONTH as FAC_MONTH, FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT.FAC_YEAR as FAC_YEAR, FAC_FILE_UPLOAD.LAST_UPDATED as LAST_UPDATED,
CASE IS_COMPLETED
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Upload'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Completed'
    END as IS_COMPLETED
FROM FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT left join FAC_FILE on FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT.FILE_ID = FAC_FILE.ID
    left join FAC_FILE_UPLOAD on FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT.FILE_UPLOAD_ID = FAC_FILE_UPLOAD.ID
    left join FAC_NHAN_VIEN on FAC_FILE_MANAGEMENT.UPLOADED_BY = FAC_NHAN_VIEN.ID;
```

Now, I want to create new custom column nam 'View Detail'. This column is a link based on value of IS_COMPLETED

- **Completed**: Show link to view detail
- **Not Upload**: Blank

How can I add a custom column into interactive report?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063834/18747) for a method using CSS to hide unwanted links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add column to your report query like:

```
,DECODE(IS_COMPLETED,'Y','<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.::::P1_FILE_NAME:' || FAC_FILE.NAME ||'">View Detail</a>','N','') AS 'Detail'
```

This will add new column to your report.

Now go to your `Report Attributes` tab and edit `Detail` Column.

and change `Display As` to `Standard Report Column`.

Also, you need to select column in interactive report to display from your output.

Comment: I don't see change 'Display As' to 'Standard Report Column'. Which version of Apex do you use? Or you can capture the image to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Its much easier if you just add NULL to the query like this

```
SELECT NULL as View_Detail, <insert other columns>
FROM TABLE
```